# Ideals generalizing maximal ideals and ideals generated by regular sequences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a local commutative Noetherian ring with maximal ideal $m$.

My questions concern 
ideals $I \subseteq m$ of $R$ such that for any non-zero number $n \in \mathbb{N}$
the $R/I$-module $I^n/I^{n+1}$ is free.

There are natural examples:

- The maximal ideal $m$ of $R$ is such an ideal.
- For any regular element $x \in m$ the cyclic ideal $(x)$ is such an ideal.
  Actually, any regular sequence $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of elements in $m$ generates such an ideal.

A Theorem by Ferrand and Vasconcelos states that
an ideal $I$ of $R$ is generated by a regular sequence if and only if it has finite projective dimension and $I/I^2$ is a free $R/I$-module.

So the remaining examples of ideals of the type above have infinite projective dimension.

Here are my questions:

1. Do such ideals have a name in commutative algebra?
2. Do they have an interpretation in algebraic geometry?
3. What is the geometric interpretation of ideals $I \subseteq m$ such that the conormal module $I/I^2$ is a free $R/I$-module?

Any comments or feedback will be appreciated!